# Transfer SQLite Database via USB-Cable

Tags: android, linux, sqlite, synchronization, usb

I developed an android app where people have to leave their details such as name, reason of visit, date etc.
The collected data is stored in a SQlite Database. To backup the data I want to store the data, that I selected already on the tablet on a seperate database. To achieve that I took an ubuntu linux pc and installed MySql. Now to the issue:
I have tried and could not find a way to transfer the data from the android device to the database on the linux device.
I want to implement a method that i trigger, when there is a connection between those two devices to transfer the data from one device to the other device. On top of that I want to add another method, that comapares both databases with each other and updates the device, which isnt up to date (this happens, when another device with the same app has new entries).
I have never worked with scripts, so that would be something, that I need help with.
It has to be a connection via cable, there is no way I use a network.

I tried to convert the database into a csv-file and thought, that maybe there would be a way, where i only transfer the csv files and compare them with each other and override them. Did not work.